# Grafana filtering in table visualization by condition

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, promql

I have some prometheus like metrics below this for all my services:

```
pods_info_total{cluster="prod",deployment_name="my-service",image="my-service-1.0",namespace="my-service-prod",secret="my-service-1.0-6eet513"} 1.0
pods_info_total{cluster="standby",deployment_name="my-service",image="my-service-2.0",namespace="my-service-standby",secret="my-service-2.0-5bea640"} 1.0
```

These metrics are in table visualization and I want to compare image versions for each deployment_name. If image versions for our deployment_name for standby and prod are different, I should visualize only rows for which the given condition is true and paint it over with a given color.

How can I do something like this in Grafana?